# PrimeFaces sideMenu load Content on Click in LayoutUnit

Tags: java, primefaces

I build my first UI with PrimeFaces.

[Menue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdjF5.png)

How can I load Content in the Layout Center, by click on a menu entry.

Comment: I hope that you have learned JSF already. What part do you dont understand? Creating a template? Linking to other pages? Including a template in your page?

Comment: Or are you trying to create a single page application with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you did your div and included your menu so only thing rest is:

```
<p:menuitem value="value" url="yourContent.xhtml" />
```